# Trim string from whitespace (without changing field values)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to compare two columns and look for a matching name and one of these columns sometime include several whitespaces in it's value. The columns i need to compare are located in different tables in different databases. Basicaly it's two different person registries and there seem to be a bug in the GUI for one of these registries that puts whitespace in to the database.

The name-column in one of the registries sometimes contains persons with two lastnames with a hyphen, like "Andersen-Johnson", whilst the corresponding value in the other table might contain one of these names (ex Johnson) but it also contains several whitespaces. I would like to use "LIKE" to find Johnson in Andersen-Johnson but it will obsviously not work if Johnson contains whitespaces.

Se the actual string values between the quote marks below:

```
Column A: "Andersen-Johnson"
Column B: "Johnson                "
```

So my question is: is there a way to trim the values in the name column for comparison without changing the value of the column itself?

Comment: The `replace` function? It will perform terribly though. Maybe a computed column with the adjusted values.

Comment: `ColumnA LIKE CONCAT('%', RTRIM(ColumnB), '%')` perhaps?

Comment: Have you considered using SSIS Fuzzy Lookup to find matches? It sounds like trimming is only one of your problems a simple `LIKE` cannot solve.

Comment: @Nick I tried your suggestion and it seem to do what i need. If you'll post your suggestion as an answer i'll mark it as answered

Comment: @Filburt I'm not familiar with this. There's a time aspect so i would prefer a more straight forward alternative.

Comment: It's basically the same as @VBoka answer you may as well accept that

Comment: @Nick yes i know, it's done. Thank you

Comment: @WhoAmI See [Fuzzy Lookup Transformation documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/fuzzy-lookup-transformation?view=sql-server-ver15) and an [Fuzzy Transformation example](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5644/fuzzy-transformation-and-fuzzy-grouping-in-sql-server-integration-services/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand you but is this what you need:

```
select * 
from tbl
where c_a like concat('%',trim(c_b),'%')
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5d466fb75b4358d6651b48fa4dcc4b1c)

Comment: Hi @WhoAmI , you are welcome, happy to help. Cheers!